# Initial pressure of explosion

Tags: pressure, explosions

I would like to know, if given a TNT equivalent of explosive (or its Energy) is it possible to determine what would be the initial pressure that will be the result of that explosion ?

To be more precise let's say I have a vessel and given the vessel volume can I determine pressure inside that vessel (assuming vessel won't break).

Comment: Ideal gas law suggests $P\propto E/V$, so your first question is an affirmative. For the latter question, you'd need to know the number of moles and the temperature of the gas in the vessel in addition to the volume to determine the pressure.

Comment: I would also suggest the ideal gas law (or van der Waals equation). But also keep in mind that the entire explosive reaction might not happen instantaneous, so it might also depend on your definition of the initial pressure. For instance at the end of the reaction, when all the explosives have reacted, but the explosion would have expanded in volume already.

Comment: As commented by @fibonatic, the true initial pressure do depend on the explosive reaction: how fast can you inject energy into a small volume matters. If that vessel is large enough, there will be a shock wave expanding from the center of explosion. In that case, Sedov's solution may be helpful to determine the pressure profile.

Comment: I have asked a similar question on Chemistry Stack Exchange.  Because I believe the answer doesn't like with pure "physics". http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8866/

Answer (score 1):

According to [New Energetic Materials](http://www.wiley-vch.de/books/sample/3527302409_c01.pdf), table 1.2, 19.5 GigaPascals (GPa) is the initial pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming energy is does not leak out of the vessel, after enough time has passed$^{[1]}$ the gas will have homogenised. Also, no gas molecules will leak in or out. Assume the vessel doesn't have the time$^{[2]}$ to expand, and as air is mostly diatomic,

$$E=\frac{5}{2}kT.$$
Now, 
$$P= \frac{NkT}{V}=\frac{2E}{5V}.$$

The only problem remaining  is to check that $[1]$ and $[2]$ aren't contradictory.

Comment: If we assume complete combustion, then $E$ is the variable which is absolutely known.  But this is likely refuted by chemical equilibrium.  Higher pressure correlates with the reaction products, so higher pressure would push it to incomplete combustion, I think.  Otherwise, we can determine $N$ from the initial density, which is solid, and keep the final density the same.  This would be superficially sufficient from the basis of physics, but I think chemistry experts may be necessary to fully answer due to my prior argument.